# Matrix valued Geometric Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

A (driftless) Geometric Brownian Motion is characterized by the scalar SDE:

$dS_t = \sigma S_tdB_t$

with $B_t$ a standard Brownian Motion (BM).

I am interested in the $d \times d$-dimensional SDE for $d \geq 2$:

$dX_t = \sigma X_t dW_t$

where $X_t$ is a $\mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$-valued stochastic process, $W_t$ is a $d \times d$ matrix of independent standard BMs, and $X_t dW_t$ stands for matrix multiplication, i.e. for $i,j = 1,\dots,d$:

$[dX_t]_{i,j} = \sigma \sum_{k=1}^d [X_t]_{i,k} [dW_t]_{k,j}$

$[X_T]_{i,j} = [X_0]_{i,j} + \sigma \sum_{k=1}^d \int_{0}^T [X_t]_{i,k} [dW_t]_{k,j}$

Has this process been studied already, and if so what would be a reference?

I am mainly interested in whether an explicit solution can be found.